# CPU power more than motherboard support wattage

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a hardware question.

I'm trying to build a  [shuttle computer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IXFFD4W) . The power [specs on page 4](http://www.shuttle.eu/fileadmin/resources/download/docs/spec/barebones/DS81_e.pdf) says it can handle only max 65 watt processor. Every processor I'm looking at is over that wattage. What happens when if I put  [this core i5 processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/75038/Intel-Core-i5-4440-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz)  onto the motherboard, will it work?

It's funny that when I pull the shuttle item up on amazon, it says the item is frequently bought with the core i7 processor. That thing is definitely over 65 watts. So I guess it some how works? I wanted to check to make sure.

Comment: That i5 doesn't require a minimum 84W, that's just the maximum it is designed to draw for an extended period at high CPU %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Specification you are saying is about not the use of power Wattage. It is saying about the  maximum TDP

> Thermal Design Power (TDP) represents the near maximum power a product can draw for a thermally significant period while running commercially available software. For thermal solution requirements please consult the Datasheet, volume 1 (where available).

*Source Intel*.

So it is saying about the maximum Thermal Design power the CPU can handle

the unit here used for heat is watt

> In many applied fields in engineering the British thermal unit (BTU) and the calorie are often used. The standard unit for the rate of heat transferred is the watt (W), defined as joules per second. *Wikipedia*

the Maximum TDP will not reach more than `15W`so you don't need to think about it your shuttle will run fine and smoothly.

The TDP will be depend on your applications that you are running on your system.

> The thermal design power (TDP), sometimes called thermal design point, refers to the maximum amount of heat generated by the CPU, which the cooling system in a computer is required to dissipate in typical operation. Rather than specifying CPU's real power dissipation, TDP serves as the nominal value for designing CPU cooling systems.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power)
>
> The TDP is typically not the largest amount of heat the CPU could ever generate (peak power), such as by running a power virus, but rather the maximum amount of heat that it would generate when running "real applications." This ensures the computer will be able to handle essentially all applications without exceeding its thermal envelope, or requiring a cooling system for the maximum theoretical power (which would cost more but in favor of extra headroom for processing power).[2]
>
> Some sources state that the peak power for a microprocessor is usually 1.5 times the TDP rating.[3] However, the TDP is a conventional figure while its measurement methodology has been the subject of controversy. In particular, until around 2006 AMD used to report the maximum power draw of its processors as TDP, but Intel changed this practice with the introduction of its Conroe family of processors.[4]

For more information about this read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power)

So go for it nothing will happen to your system.

> Every processor I'm looking at is over that wattage.

It is not true. see this.http://ark.intel.com/products/family/75024/4th-Generation-Intel-Core-i5-Processors#@All

Comment: why there is no upvote...